# Typescript - Complex Object merge with Dot Notation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I want to display the data in a Tree View in Angular and need to transform an array of dot-notated elements into a collection of objects with children.

[This](https://pastebin.com/A5QyBkLm) is the array I'm working with. Notice the **key** field in every element.

So the structure I need is for example (for the first 4 elements in the array):

```js
    const data = [
    {
        key: 'bs',
        children: [
            {
                key: 'ass',
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 'fixAss',
                        decimals: '0',
                        unitRef: 'unit_euro',
                        contextRef: 'period_2019',
                        value: 15542000,
                        children: [
                            {
                                key: 'intan',
                                decimals: '0',
                                unitRef: 'unit_euro',
                                contextRef: 'period_2019',
                                value: 8536000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        key: 'concessionBrands',
                                        decimals: '0',
                                        unitRef: 'unit_euro',
                                        contextRef: 'period_2019',
                                        value: 8536000,
                                        children: [] // If there are no children in the element this can be empty or left out
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                key: 'tan',
                                decimals: '0',
                                unitRef: 'unit_euro',
                                contextRef: 'period_2019',
                                value: 6890000,
                                children: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

That means elements are combined by having a *key* attribute which holds the notation for that level (i.e "bs", "ass", "fixAss", ...) and then children of the next level. An element can have values of its own ("decimals", "unitRef",...) and might additionally also have children that are made up the same way. There is no restriction on the amount of levels this can have.

I have the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [dot object](https://github.com/rhalff/dot-object) libraries in my package.json. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, can you provide an example?

Comment: I get this https://pastebin.com/A5QyBkLm array from our Backend. I want to transform that data into the form you can see in the code example in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the dot-object lib has no things to work with something like "children" that you have, so it seems custom code is required to build what you expected

```
// balanceData got somehow

let data = [];
const getOrBuildPathObject = (path) => {
   let currentLevel = data;
   let obj = null;
   for(let keyFragment of path.split('.')) {
      obj = currentLevel.find(v => v.key == keyFragment);
      if(!obj) {
        obj = {key: keyFragment, children: []};
        currentLevel.push(obj);
      }
      currentLevel = obj.children;
   }
   return obj;
}

balanceData.forEach((d) => {
  let {key, ...data} = d;
  Object.assign(getOrBuildPathObject(key), data);
})
```

should be something like that

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I was thinking about this all morning -.-

Comment: was it working from the very beginning without any edits? I didn't test it at all

Comment: Yes it work flawlessly. The IDE just comllains about a shadowed variable in the {key, ...data} part.

Answer (score 1):

I would just iterate through the array and check each key.

Split the key at the dots `myArray.split('.')` returns an array.
Now iterate through that array and create an Object for each element.

Like
`bs.ass.fixAss`

- Check if a root element `bs` exists.

  - If no, create an (empty) `bs` Element.
- Check if an `ass` element is a child of `bs`

  - If no, create an (empty) `ass` Element
- Check if an (empty) `fixAss` Element exists.

  - If no, create the `fixAss` Element with values and add it as child to the `ass` Element
  - If yes, fill the values

If its guaranteed that the data will always be in the right order (that means `bs.ass.fixAss` will always be AFTER `bs.ass`) then you may skip the checks.

I would use a HashMap for the children (not an array), because that makes it much easier to walk through the tree
`myTrees[bs].children[ass].children[fixAss]`

The whole thing could be created with plain TypesScript. I do not know any library that would solve this specific problem out of the box.